# How to fix page refresh issues in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, routes

When I hit F5 / refresh the webpage I get a 404 not found error on my react app hosted by apache 2.2

I am running reactjs with react boot strap and routes

I have seen online ppl have added a `.htaccess` file in the public folder and then built the app but this has not worked for me

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,
        Route,
        Link,
        Switch,
        Redirect
 } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Test from './components/Test';
import Test1 from './components/Test1';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/test" component={Test} />
          <Route exact path="/test1" component={Test1} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you do the refresh when you're not in the root.

I use this `.htaccess` file for my app to make the routes work properly

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: and do you put that in to the public folder before you run npm run build ? or do you add after?

Comment: doesn't matter :)))

Comment: Still no joy .. i just get Not Found
The requested URL /test was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue and we used the following setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/httpd/example.com

  <Directory "/var/www/httpd/example.com">
    ...

    RewriteEngine on
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

We got this configuration from [here](https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/react-router-in-the-real/content/apache.html).